# Facebook groups_access_member_info problem

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

Please, I would like to read comments of posts from my Facebook private group and **user info** (name, id, etc.) who did make the comment.
I created an app with permission groups_access_member_info and added it into the Facebook private group but in the facebook API response I can see **only my** name and ID and I can not see others names or at least their IDs.

I see this (two comments, but I see **only my** user info "from:" :
[image]

But I would like to see something like this as Facebook documents:
[image]

The app is in Live mode and I when I want to add it into the private group I see this (there is written "After adding the app into group you will be able: To see post and comments in the group, but not who has written them"):
[image]

Can anyoune please help me what can I do wrong?
I am concerned about the last screenshot that I added here as there is written ".... but not who has written them" But teh app has permisson groups_access_member_info

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Here is what a user grant to our App but his name is not seen in the response:
[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/groups_access_member_info_description/: _"The groups_access_member_info permission allows your app to read publicly available group member information like name and ID **if the post author has granted your app access.**"_ - so unless these users logged into your app and granted it at least `public_profile` permission, you can not get this data.

Comment: (P.s., if you would (temporarily) set your Facebook's account language to English before taking such screenshots, we could check everything it says in there ourselves directly, and you would not have to manually translate for us ...)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for answer, but as I as a user (Petr Kott) I allow everything and the Facebook does not return my name in my comments.  
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ7NQ.png

Comment: What are you talking about now, you explicitly said _"I see this (two comments, but I see **only my** user info from:"_ before ...?

Comment: I mean that in response, there is not a **user info** (from[name,surname, etc.]) of other users. There is info only about me. I need a user info (from[name,surname, etc.]) from all who comments.

Comment: Those other users would have to give your app the same permission you did, before you can get their info.

Comment: I understand, but they gave us all permissions that is required. And it does not work

Comment: Did you get the use of this functionality approved in review already? Are you dev or live mode?

Comment: We are in live mode. We have the functionality approved